# How to merge three paths and fill with gradient

Tags: svg, merge, path, gradient

I created three paths:

```
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 10 100 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
  <path d="M 10 90 C 40 00, 65 00, 95 70 S 150 140, 180 70" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/> 
  <path d="M250 75 L180 120 L180 30 Z" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

How can I merge the paths and fill them with a gradient? I also created a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/465wmnjx/14/) for this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to merge the three paths you join the d attributes in one. However since in this case both curves are drawn in the same direction I reversed one of them and changed the initial command (`M`) to a line `L`.
I hope this is what you need.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="lg">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(120,100%,30%)"></stop>
   <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(320,100%,50%)"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
  <path d="M 10 100 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80
           L180,70C150,140 125,140 95,70C65,00 40,00 10,90
           M250 75 L180 120 L180 30 Z" stroke="black" fill="url(#lg)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! Great! Thank you :)

Comment: ... one more thing. How can I make the gradient extent not from left to right but from the start of the arrow to the end of the arrow?

Comment: ah got it" `gradientTransform="rotate(65)"`